# how get particular JSON block find by value from main JSON Object using json in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have find particular JSON block find by Value from main JSON below is the json

```
mainJSON = [{ "name":"John", "car":"Scorpio" },{ "name":"John", "car":"Maruti800" },{ "name":"Priya", "car":"BMW" },{ "name":"Nick", "car":"Audi" }, { "name":"Nick", "car":"Bentley" }]
```

search all json block find by name "Jonh"

like below OUTPUT

```
{ "name":"John", "car":"Scorpio" }
{ "name":"John", "car":"Maruti800" }
```

```
import json

data = json.load(mainJSON)
```

Please help me here to find block in quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in mainJSON if x.get('name') == 'John']
```